# general formula of an alternating sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence

$s_n = \sqrt{n}$ for n = 1, 4, 9, 16, .... (square number)

$s_n = n $ for everything other positive integers.

Find the general formula of the sequence.

I tried different things and I'm still stuck on this problem. I think the general term should be something like this

$\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}^{k(n)}$ for $k(n)$ is some alternating function equals to 0 when n is a square number, equals to 1 when k is not a square number. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $\phi$ be the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), how about $$s_n=(\sqrt n)^{(n-\phi(n)\bmod2)+1}$$This is based on the fact that $n-\phi(n)$ is even iff $n$ is a perfect square.